# vagrant isn't picking up shared folders from homestead.yaml

Tags: vagrant, homestead

this is the homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: rd-cp.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/rd-cp/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

when I run `vagrant up` I get a vm but `/home/vagrant/Code` is empty. The target folder exists, there just appears to be no attempt by vagrant to map to it.

Bootup says:

```
 default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/me/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/0.5.0/virtualbox
```

no mention of Code.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: isnt `C:/Code` in the yaml file ? and have the `Code` folder created under your C drive

Comment: Sorry Frédéric I don't understand what you mean?  The reference to C:\Code is there in the homestead.yaml and yes, C:\Code exists

Comment: Nevertheless give a try with `C:/Code` - replacing \ by /

Comment: tried them both; C:\Code and C:/Code.  Neither work

Answer (score 2):

The issue with Homestead is unresolved, but I was able to work around it very simply by editing the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Code", "/home/vagrant/Code"
```

and that's it, that's all it took.